# Serverless: TypeError: Cannot read property 'stage' of undefined

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless

```
frameworkVersion: '2'

plugins:
  - serverless-step-functions
  - serverless-python-requirements
  - serverless-parameters
  - serverless-pseudo-parameters

provider:
  name: aws
  region: us-east-2
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  runtime: python3.7
  versionFunctions: false
  iam:
    role: arn:aws:iam::#{AWS::AccountId}:role/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole
  apiGateway:
    shouldStartNameWithService: true
  lambdaHashingVersion: 20201221 

package:
  exclude:
    - node_modules/**
    - venv/**

# Lambda functions
functions:
  generateAlert:
    handler: handler.generateAlert

  generateData:
    handler: handler.generateDataHandler
    timeout: 600

  approveDenied:
    handler: handler.approveDenied
    timeout: 600
stepFunctions:
  stateMachines:
    "claims-etl-and-insight-generation-${self:provider.stage}":
      loggingConfig:
        level: ALL
        includeExecutionData: true
        destinations:
          - Fn::GetAtt: ["ETLStepFunctionLogGroup", Arn]
      name: "claims-etl-and-insight-generation-${self:provider.stage}"
      definition:
        Comment: "${self:provider.stage} ETL Workflow"
        StartAt: RawQualityJob
        States:

          # Raw Data Quality Check Job Start
          RawQualityJob:
            Type: Task
            Resource: arn:aws:states:::glue:startJobRun.sync
            Parameters:
              JobName: "data_quality_v2_${self:provider.stage}"
              Arguments:
                "--workflow-name": "${self:provider.stage}-Workflow"
                "--dataset_id.$": "$.datasetId"
                "--client_id.$": "$.clientId"
            Next: DataQualityChoice
            Retry:
              - ErrorEquals: [States.ALL]
                MaxAttempts: 2
                IntervalSeconds: 10
                BackoffRate: 5
            Catch:
              - ErrorEquals: [States.ALL]
                Next: GenerateErrorAlertDataQuality
          # End Raw Data Quality Check Job

          DataQualityChoice:
            Type: Task
            Resource:
              Fn::GetAtt: [approveDenied, Arn]
            Next: Is Approved ?

          Is Approved ?:
            Type: Choice
            Choices:
              - Variable: "$.quality_status"
                StringEquals: "Denied"
                Next: FailState
            Default: HeaderLineJob

          FailState:
            Type: Fail
            Cause: "Denied status"

          # Header Line Job Start
          HeaderLineJob:
            Type: Parallel
            Branches:
              - StartAt: HeaderLineIngestion
                States:
                  HeaderLineIngestion:
                    Type: Task
                    Resource: arn:aws:states:::glue:startJobRun.sync
                    Parameters:
                      JobName: headers_lines_etl_rs_v2
                      Arguments:
                        "--workflow-name.$": "$.Arguments.--workflow-name"
                        "--dataset_id.$": "$.Arguments.--dataset_id"
                        "--client_id.$": "$.Arguments.--client_id"
                    End: True
                    Retry:
                      - ErrorEquals: [States.ALL]
                        MaxAttempts: 2
                        IntervalSeconds: 10
                        BackoffRate: 5
                    Catch:
                      - ErrorEquals: [States.ALL]
                        Next: GenerateErrorAlertHeaderLine
            End: True
          # Header Line Job End

          GenerateErrorAlertDataQuality:
            Type: Task
            Resource:
              Fn::GetAtt: [generateAlert, Arn]
            End: true

 resources:
  Resources:

    # Cloudwatch Log
    "ETLStepFunctionLogGroup":
      Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup
      Properties:
        LogGroupName: "ETLStepFunctionLogGroup_${self:provider.stage}"
```

This is what my serverless.yml file looks like.

When I run the command:

`sls deploy --stage staging`

It show

Type Error ----------------------------------------------

TypeError: Cannot read property 'stage' of undefined
at Variables.getValueFromOptions (/snapshot/serverless/lib/classes/Variables.js:648:37)
at Variables.getValueFromSource (/snapshot/serverless/lib/classes/Variables.js:579:17)
at /snapshot/serverless/lib/classes/Variables.js:539:12

Your Environment Information ---------------------------
Operating System:          linux
Node Version:              14.4.0
Framework Version:         2.30.3 (standalone)
Plugin Version:            4.5.1
SDK Version:               4.2.0
Components Version:        3.7.4

How I can fix this? I tried with different version of serverless.
There is error in yamlParser file, which is provided by serverless-step-functions.
Above is my serverless config file.

Comment: In most cases, this is due to a misconfiguration or spelling errors in the serverless yml file. Can you please post your whole serverless config file?

Comment: @ReazMurshed, I have updated the post please check

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a `$` sign is missing from your provider -> stage?

```
provider:
  name: aws
  region: us-east-2
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'} # $ sign is missing?
  runtime: python3.7
  versionFunctions: false
  iam:
    role: arn:aws:iam::#{AWS::AccountId}:role/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole
  apiGateway:
    shouldStartNameWithService: true
  lambdaHashingVersion: 20201221
```

Comment: Sorry I made a typo. It's ``` stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}``` in serverless file